# JavaScript Scope - populating text box with multiple selections

Tags: javascript, scope

I'm sorry for asking a question that I'm sure is simple but I'm stuck. I have a project that requires the user to select 3 notes, the value for each should populate in the text box until the 3rd is entered. After that a compare is done to an array and a notification sent to the user letting them know if they have made a valid selection or not.
The problem I'm having is getting all 3 to populate, each time I click a button it overwrites the existing value. I've tried to push them to an array but it only contains the current value, I've tried a loop but that populates the selection 3x. I'm sure I'm overlooking something simple but have not been able to figure out what it is. Can someone point me in the right direction?
Thanks!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Scope </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    html {
      height: 100%;
    }
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
      font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    div#container {
       margin: auto;
       width: 300px;
    }
    form {
       margin-top: 20%;
    }
    form input[type="text"] {
       font-size: 120%;
       text-align: center;
    }
    form input[type="button"] {
       background-color: lightblue;
       font-size: 110%;
    }
</style>

<script>
   function addNote(event) {

      var validChords = {
         C: "CEG",
         F: "FAC",
         G: "GBD"
      };  

      var note = event.target.value;
      console.log(note);   

      var getNotes = [];
      var noteDisplay = document.getElementById("notesDisplay");
      var displayMessage = document.getElementById("message");

      getNotes.push(note);
      console.log(getNotes);

      noteDisplay.value = getNotes;
      noteDisplay.innterHTML = getNotes;
      displayMessage.innterHTML = "Please Enter Antoher Note!";

//Code below is different things I've been playing with trying to
// figure this out.  

//  var success = false;
//  if (notes.length > 0) {
//    if (note) {
//     for (var i =0; i < 3; i++) {
//       if(notes[i] == note) {
//         var found = true;
//         getNotes.push(note);
//     }
//    }     
//   }   
//  }   
 // if (getNotes.length < 3) {
  // }           

}              

window.onload = function() {
 var notes = ["C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "B"];

 var cButton = document.getElementById("c");
 cButton.onclick = addNote;
 var dButton = document.getElementById("d");
 dButton.onclick = addNote;
 var eButton = document.getElementById("e");
 eButton.onclick = addNote;
 var fButton = document.getElementById("f");
 fButton.onclick = addNote;
 var gButton = document.getElementById("g");
 gButton.onclick = addNote;
 var aButton = document.getElementById("a");
 aButton.onclick = addNote;
 var bButton = document.getElementById("b");
 bButton.onclick = addNote;

// your code here    
} 
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
<form>
  <p id="message">Enter a major triad chord:</p>
  <p>
  <input id="notesDisplay" type="text" size="21">
 </p>
 <p>
   <input id="c" type="button" value="C">
   <input id="d" type="button" value="D">
   <input id="e" type="button" value="E">
   <input id="f" type="button" value="F">
   <input id="g" type="button" value="G">
   <input id="a" type="button" value="A">
   <input id="b" type="button" value="B">
</p>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I finally figured out how to get the entries and compare to the object containing specific values and return either a note or a message to try again.  I'm almost there but am having an issue with my loops (I think). When a button is clicked a message is supposed to display saying "please enter another note" until the 3rd selection is made, when the first button is clicked I'm getting the "you have made an invalid selection message" and I don't understand why. The last piece I'm missing is the form is supposed to clear after either message is displayed. This is driving me nuts, can someone give me a hint as to what I still have wrong? Thanks!

Revised Code:
    
    
      
       Scope 
      
    
      html {
        height: 100%;
      }
      body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
      }
      div#container {
        margin: auto;
        width: 300px;
      }
      form {
        margin-top: 20%;
      }
      form input[type="text"] {
        font-size: 120%;
        text-align: center;
      }
      form input[type="button"] {
        background-color: lightblue;
        font-size: 110%;
      }

```
//Array to hold notes entered by user, counter to hold number of 
//buttons clicked
var getNotes = [];   
var counter = 0;

//addNote function, collects the notes entered by the user and displays 
//them in the text box. When the number of notes entered equals 3 a 
//compare is done to the validChords object. If the notes equal a valid 
//chord a messages is displayed to the user telling them which chord was 
//entered, if the chord is not correct a message is displayed telling 
//them to try again. After either the form should be cleared.

function addNote(event) {
  var validChords = {
     C: "CEG",
     F: "FAC",
     G: "GBD"
  };

  var note = event.target.value;
  var noteDisplay = document.getElementById("notesDisplay");
  var displayMessage = document.getElementById("message");

  if (counter <= 3)  {
    getNotes.push(note);
    var removeComma = "";

    for (i = getNotes.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
       removeComma = getNotes[i]+removeComma;
    }   

   noteDisplay.value = removeComma;
   noteDisplay.innerHTML = removeComma;
   displayMessage.innerHTML = "Please Enter Antoher Note!";
   counter = counter+1;
} 

 if (counter == 3) {
    for (var prop in validChords) {
      if (removeComma === validChords[prop]) {
      displayMessage.innerHTML = "You have entered a " + prop + "    
         Chord!";
      notesDisplay.innterHTML = " ";
      counter = 0;
      } 
    } 
 } else {
    displayMessage.innerHTML = "You have not entered a valid chord, 
       please try again!";
    notesDisplay.innterHTML = " ";
    counter = 0;
   }
  }    

    window.onload = function() {
    var notes = ["C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "B"];

    var cButton = document.getElementById("c");
    cButton.onclick = addNote;
    var dButton = document.getElementById("d");
    dButton.onclick = addNote;
    var eButton = document.getElementById("e");
    eButton.onclick = addNote;
    var fButton = document.getElementById("f");
    fButton.onclick = addNote;
    var gButton = document.getElementById("g");
    gButton.onclick = addNote;
    var aButton = document.getElementById("a");
    aButton.onclick = addNote;
    var bButton = document.getElementById("b");
    bButton.onclick = addNote;

   } 
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<form>
  <p id="message">Enter a major triad chord:</p>
  <p>
  <input id="notesDisplay" type="text" size="21">
  </p>
  <p>
   <input id="c" type="button" value="C">
   <input id="d" type="button" value="D">
   <input id="e" type="button" value="E">
   <input id="f" type="button" value="F">
   <input id="g" type="button" value="G">
   <input id="a" type="button" value="A">
   <input id="b" type="button" value="B">
  </p>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You do want to push into an array. Your problem, however, is that you keep resetting the local array. Move its declaration outside of your `addNote` function.

Comment: Oh, and the misspelling also explains why my message was not changing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's because you initialize getNote to an empty array every time you call the addNote function, check if that is the problem.

Thanks